Como limitar sugestões de endereço usando a biblioteca @react-google-maps/api?
Estou usando a lib @react-google-maps/api para fazer um app de transporte. Queria saber como faço para limitar as sugestões de endereço do autocomplete para mostrar apenas endereços de determinado país, estado etc. Se alguém souber como fazer e puder explicar agradeço.

Boas-vindas. Essa pergunta já foi feita, e as devidas orientações foram fornecidas via comentário. Se precisar comentar ou revisar a a dúvida, para comunidade conseguir ajudar, faça na pergunta original.
